# PowerShell: Create Local User Account

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to create a new local user account, and then add them to the local **Administrators** group. Can this be done in PowerShell?

EDIT:

```
# Create new local Admin user for script purposes
$Computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Env:COMPUTERNAME,Computer"

$LocalAdmin = $Computer.Create("User", "LocalAdmin")
$LocalAdmin.SetPassword("Password01")
$LocalAdmin.SetInfo()
$LocalAdmin.FullName = "Local Admin by Powershell"
$LocalAdmin.SetInfo()
$LocalAdmin.UserFlags = 64 + 65536 # ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE + ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
$LocalAdmin.SetInfo()
```

I have this, but was wondering if there is anything more PowerShell-esque.

Comment: What isn't Powershell-esque about that? Not everything is a cmdlet - but that doesn't mean you can't wrap the code above in a function of your own to make it feel like one.

Comment: Powershell-esque is cmdlets & pipelines; this is C++

Comment: @bwerks - if cmdlets and pipelines are what PowerShell means to you then  you're entirely missing out on the "power" part of PowerShell -- .NET, COM Interfaces, Reflection, Platform Invocation, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: I had to use your ADSI method as `New-LocalUser` was throwing errors about not meeting password complexity requirements.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Another alternative is the old school [NET USER](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771865.aspx) commands:

`NET USER username "password" /ADD`

OK - you can't set all the options but it's a lot less convoluted for simple user creation & easy to script up in Powershell.

`NET LOCALGROUP "group" "user" /add` to set group membership.

Comment: Calling out to `net.exe` strikes me as being _less_ "PowerShell-esque" than the original ADSI code; there is nothing indicative of PowerShell in those commands, and you could drop them in, say, a batch file and they'd work just the same.  To me, this eschews the **Power** of an object-oriented **Shell** and reverts back to having to deal with application-specific command syntaxes, exit codes, and error messages.  To be fair, though, there's really two different questions that have been asked here: "How can I do this in PowerShell?" and "I can do this in PowerShell.  How can I do it better?"

Comment: FWIW I ran into an issue with a PowerShell function I wrote to wrap "NET USER /ADD" call. Specifically, if the password was longer than 14 characters, the NET USER commandline would prompt for input from the user to confirm Y/N. There is no commandline option in NET USER to provide that confirmation so that will "freeze" PS scripts that are run non-interactively.

Comment: @Jaans, you can override that prompt by issuing /Y at the end:
`net user $name $password /add /fullname:$full /passwordchg:no /Y`

Answer (score 45):

As of PowerShell 5.1 there cmdlet `New-LocalUser` which could create local user account.

Example of usage:

Create a user account

```
New-LocalUser -Name "User02" -Description "Description of this account." -NoPassword
```

or Create a user account that has a password

```
$Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
New-LocalUser "User03" -Password $Password -FullName "Third User" -Description "Description of this account."
```

or Create a user account that is connected to a Microsoft account

```
New-LocalUser -Name "MicrosoftAccount\usr name@Outlook.com" -Description "Description of this account."
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that there is still only a preview release of PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: PowerShell 5.1 is included in Windows Server 2016. :-)

Comment: Verified that this worked on Windows 10 Enterprise, Powershell Version 5.1 Build 14393

Comment: Works on Windows 7 after nstalling WMF5.1 as well

Answer (score 12):

Try using [Carbon's](http://get-carbon.org) [Install-User](http://get-carbon.org/help/Install-User.html) and [Add-GroupMember](http://get-carbon.org/help/Add-GroupMember.html) functions:

```
Install-User -Username "User" -Description "LocalAdmin" -FullName "Local Admin by Powershell" -Password "Password01"
Add-GroupMember -Name 'Administrators' -Member 'User'
```

***Disclaimer:*** I am the creator/maintainer of the Carbon project.

Comment: Hi, your get carbon was exactly what I was looking for, does it script out the mod-security for asp web sites too on 2k12r2. It would nice tosee some recommendations on security modules etc for IIS and defending the Server.

Comment: @aggie See the [Carbon docs](http://get-carbon.org/documentation.html) for the full list of its capabilities.

Comment: me likey, looks well maintained.  won't be long before i carbonize our base module for deployment scripts.  i might have some contribs down the line.  thanks @aaronjensen et al!

Answer (score 8):

As of 2014, [here is a statement](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/10/02/use-powershell-to-create-local-groups/) from a Microsoft representative (the Scripting Guy):

> As much as we might hate to admit it, there are still no Windows
>   PowerShell cmdlets from Microsoft that permit creating local user
>   accounts or local user groups. We finally have a Desired State
>   Configuration (DSC ) provider that can do this—but to date, no
>   cmdlets.

Answer (score 1):

```
Import-Csv C:\test.csv |
Foreach-Object {
  NET USER    $ _.username   $ _.password /ADD
  NET LOCALGROUP "group" $_.username  /ADD
}
```

edit csv as username,password
and change "group" for your groupname

:) worked on 2012 R2

Answer (score 0):

```
$sec_pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "SomePasword" -AsPlainText -Force
New-LocalUser -Name username -FullName username -PasswordNeverExpires -Password $sec_pass
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member username
```