# Getting an "Access Denied" error when executing PS code as an Administrator

Tags: powershell, adsi

Tried the code I found on this SO question:
[PowerShell: Create Local User Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167069/powershell-create-local-user)

But when I execute it (in ISE running in the context of a Domain Admin acct, on a PC where Domain Admins are in the local Adminstrators group) I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0" argument(s): "Access is denied.
"
At \\servername\scripts\powershell\create-local-user.ps1:6 char:1
+ $LocalAdmin.SetInfo()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI
```

Why would I be getting an "Access Denied" exception with the `SetInfo()` method in this case?

Comment: Are you running in an elevated ISE session?

Comment: @mjolinor Yes, I am...

Comment: Could you share the relevant portions of `create-local-user.ps1`?

Comment: mjolinor means, did you right-click the ISE shortcut and specifically request to run it as administrator? If UAC is enabled, your account being a member of Administrators isn't enough for applications to actually run as administrator. You must request it specifically.

Answer (score 1):

@Bill_Stewart identified the problem -- even though I was running ISE under an account that has domain admin priv's via a "runas" script, i.e.:
`runas /user:domain-admin@company.com "powershell_ise.exe"`
it still will not work on systems with UAC enabled (as mine is, running Win7 Pro) without right-clicking the ISE icon, selecting "Run as administrator" and then authenticating with a (domain) admin account.

Comment: Not possible Redirect output for powershell and use run as administrator, I think.