# this code my teacher gave it to us as homework and it does not work with me idk why

Tags: powershell

Based on the following .ps1 program. Write a program that checks for the user "shu", if not present it will create it.

```
Write-Host "checking users"$testUser="hgallo"
$checkUser = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True'"  | Select-String -Pattern $testUser

if($checkUser -ne $null) {
  Write-Host "user $testUser found"
} else {
  Write-Host "user $testUser not found"    
}
```

this is my homework and im not good at coding guys 
can you help me pleases.

Here is the error `Select-String`:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is null. 
At line:1 char:107 
+ $checkUser=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True'"  | select-string -pattern <<<<  $tes tUser     
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-St
```

Comment: The question has some serious formatting problems. It's hard to say whether it's just bad copy-paste or it is real code. Either way, this might be just a typo in the first `write-host` statement or something way different. As of now, it's all guessning.

Answer (score 2):

VonPryz is correct,

Please try the below code

```
Write-Host "checking users"
$testUser="hgallo"

$checkUser = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True'"  | Select-String -Pattern $testUser

if($checkUser -ne $null) {
  Write-Host "user $testUser found"
} else {
  Write-Host "user $testUser not found"    
}
```

The error in the code was stating that the `-Pattern` parameter was failing because the variable `$testuser` was null. This was because of the formatting on your first line of code.

Incorrectly Formatted Code:

```
Write-Host "checking users"$testUser="hgallo"
```

Correctly Formatted Code:

```
Write-Host "checking users"
$testUser="hgallo"
```

Comment: thank you VonPryz, it worked but i did not find the complete answer yet because mt teacher wants me to checks for the user "shu", if not present it will create it. if i type my user name Fahad will check if it exist  will say found or not exist say not found . i need to add more tool to chech the user name

Comment: Hi Fahad, this forum isnt designed to complete your homework, the code you had provided in your question had an issue. That was what i highlighted in my answer. If you are searching for a complete script to solve your problem you will not find it here

Comment: ok thank you im almost done with it but i have this issue please help me to fix it, i want ot add SHU user and output give me its found i added it but say wrong idk where is the problems.                                         Write-Host "checking users"
$testUser="hgallo"



$checkUser = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True'"  | Select-String -Pattern $testUser

if($checkUser -ne $null) {
$testUser="shu"
  Write-Host "user $testUser found"
} else {
   
  Write-Host "user $testUser not found"    
}

Comment: What issue is that?

Comment: i want to add new user in this code and i wrote this command $testUser="shu"   inside if statment to add this user calleed shu and say its found but i didnt work

Comment: all you are doing there is creating a variable called '$testUser' and adding a string "shu" to it. 

Look into this link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167069/powershell-create-local-user-account